# how to reuse custom actionbar to all the activities in an application?

Tags: android

I have created a custom action bar which works fine on my starting activity but gives an error when I call the method from other activities in the same application.

This is the code I am using to set the ActionBar in my first activity

**firstAct.java**

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            actionBarSetup(this);
}

    void actionBarSetup(Context context) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                ActionBar ab = getActionBar();                      
                ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
                ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
                ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE)); 

                LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);
                //assign the view to the actionbar
                ab.setCustomView(v);
}
}   



    **secondAct.java**

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_pg);
    (new firstAct()).actionBarSetup(secondAct.this);
```

}

I get NullPointerException when i call `actionBarSetup()` from secondAct.java
on line `ActionBar ab = getActionBar()`.
Is it that getActionBar() cannot be called directly from other activities besides the main activity ie. firstAct.
How to call it from other Activities then?

Comment: tool bar would be far better choice as ActionBar is deprecated

Comment: You don't create new activities by calling their constructor. You have the system create and open them for you. I'm talking about the line `(new firstAct()).actionBarSetup(secondAct.this)`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: toolbar isn't compatible with the lower APIs @PankajNimgade

Comment: @EugenPechanec .. I can't understand what you are saying.... Can you please be more precise!

Comment: @R.K, you can have toolbar using support v7 library, this will save you a lot of time

Comment: @PankajNimgrade The problem is something entirely different than AB vs Toolbar. Look at the last line of code.

Comment: @R.K What is your minSdk? If it's lower than 11, you'll have no ActionBar on those old devices. If you don't need to support Android 2.3, raise the minSdk to 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't create new activities by calling their constructor. You have the system create and open them for you. I'm talking about the line

> `(new firstAct()).actionBarSetup(secondAct.this)`

What are you trying to do here?

You probably want to make the `actionBarSetup` method accessible for all classes and not just instances of `firstAct`. Then declare it like this (maybe move it to a utility class?):

```
public static void actionBarSetup(Activity activity) {
    ActionBar ab = activity.getActionBar(); // you need activity, not just context
    // ...
}
```

Then call it from other classes like this:

```
firstAct.actionBarSetup(this);
```

Making a method static detaches it from an instances resources. You were taking in second activity (`context` parameter) but asking for an action bar from instance of the first activity (essentially `this.getActionBar()`) which was not setup by system (because you misused constructor).

Note: Please use `PascalCase` notation for class names (capital first letter).

**EDIT**

Warning: Your action bar may have different styling from your activity (e.g. black toolbar and white activity). In that case using the activity's inflater to inflate contents of the action bar will produce undesired results (inverted text color mainly). The following line is safer. But it's available no sooner than API 14.

```
LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(ab.getThemedContext());
```

Comment: i agree with you, I was just thinking moving few API level up  would help

Comment: @R.K No problem. Be careful when defining utility methods. Even when you define inner classes they can and should be static most of the time. Also see my edit, it might be useful to your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You need create BaseActivity like

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

      public void actionBarSetup(Context context) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                ActionBar ab = getActionBar();                      
                ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
                ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
                ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE)); 

                LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);
                //assign the view to the actionbar
                ab.setCustomView(v);
}
}
```

then you need firstAct and secondAct extend BaseActivity then in onCreate method call actionBarSetup()

Comment: I did the same thing after your first reply.. And it works.... thanks for your reply!! :)

Answer (score 1):

This may help

```
  private void showCustoNavBar(){

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_gradient));

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actioncustomview, null);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);

}
```